# php mysql $_post does not work

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have written this code, but it does not work and I cannot find any mistake. It filters data from mysql database. Below I pasted one code without $_post form and this works fine. But I need a filter due to the high volume of data.

`

```
        include "db_connect.inc.php";

    $sql = "SELECT versicherungsnamen, franchise, praemie FROM praemien";
    $sql .= " where kanton = " . $_POST["kanton"]
        . " and franchise = ". $_POST["franchise"];
    $sql .= " order by praemie";

    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    if ($num==0) echo "Keine Datensätze gefunden";

    while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    echo $dsatz["versicherungsnamen"] . ", "
        . $dsatz["praemie"] . "<br />"; 

        mysqli_close($con);

        ?>
    </body>
</html>`
```

But when i try this code without $_post option it works fine

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <?php
include "db_connect.inc.php";
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT versicherungsnamen, franchise, praemie FROM praemien");
while ($dsatz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    echo $dsatz["versicherungsnamen"] . ","
        .$dsatz["franchise"] . ","
        .$dsatz["praemie"] . "<br />"; 
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Kanton and franchize are integers?

Comment: are u getting value in $_POST. please check it By print_r($_POST);

Comment: yes kanton and franchise are integers

sry here is the code of the form

`<html>
 <body>
 <form action ="db_eingabe.php" method="post">
  <p><input name="kanton" /> Kanton</p>
  <p><input name="franchise" /> Franchise</p>
  <p><input type="submit" /> 
  <input type ="reset" /></p>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: As @panther said if `Kanton` and `franchize` are integers than error might be somewhere else and if they were strings then you need to place quotes around them as `where kanton = '" . $_POST["kanton"]. "' and franchise = '". $_POST["franchise"]."'`

Comment: @LorenzoVarano: what returns `echo $sql`?

Comment: it returns "no data found" and this came only so it does not find anything. but i tried in phpmyadmin directly and there sql is fine

Comment: @LorenzoVarano: `echo $sql` can't return 'no data found' but SQL query.

Comment: There maybe cases where you are not passing the value correctly and the $_POST values are null. Even if you want to pass strings they should be enclosed in single quotes in that SQL statement.

Comment: @LorenzoVarano: in comment under pejman's answer you write _I tried e.g. kanton "TG" and franchise "300"_. In the first comment here I asked you if both are integers and you told yes, they are. And now you write you use eg. 'TG'?

Comment: Hi panther. Yes sorry this was a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

before select replace post vars into separate variables then use this new vars in select query.

```
$kanton = $_POST['kanton'];
$franchise = $_POST['franchise'];

$sql = "SELECT versicherungsnamen, franchise, praemie FROM praemien where kanton = " . $kanton . " and franchise = ". $franchise. " order by praemie";
```

...

Comment: sry I didn't see your post. I tried and the same issue. It returns "no data found"

Comment: What difference does it make? Even this answer doesn't explain what's wrong in the previous one.

Comment: no difference. I tried e.g. kanton "TG" and franchise "300" and it returns no data found. However, there are around 800 rows for these two variables in mysql database. As I explained at the beginning, if I do not use any form for filtering with $_post it returns all data (around 78k rows). I think there is any problem with the variables

Comment: my experience is to not use $_POST variables directly into mysql query and its not working for me in local web servers or external servers !!

Comment: first of all you can take an echo or var_dump from $_POST variables to see that values coming from form inputs !!